# Error on create directory with python in Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, directory

I'm trying to create a directory in python, but for now I'm using windows and I'm having a little trouble.

My code from app.py is:

```
    # Python Library 
    # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

    import os

    def create_directory(server_path, branch):
        if not os.path.exists(rserver_path):
           os.makedirs(rserver_path)
        os.makedirs(server_path + "/" + branch)
```

But when I run the code:

```
D:\tools\scripts>python
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from app import *
>>> create_directory('D:\temp\lixo','ProjectA_CO_4.2.x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "app.py", line 18, in create_directory
    os.makedirs(newpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 123] A sintaxe do nome do arquivo, do nome do diret¾rio ou do r¾tulo do volume estß incorreta: 'D:\temp'
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: A Widows error 123 is *The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.*.  I suggest you use `os.path.join()` to construct the path.

Comment: The backtrace shows `os.makedirs(newpath)`, which does not appear in the code you show.

Comment: Windows doesn't allow control characters such as tab (i.e. `'\t'`) in filenames. Simplify your life by using forward slashes and normalizing via `os.path.normpath`. You can usually use forward slashes directly in Windows, but there are edge cases, so I recommend normalizing string literals that use forward slashes. pathlib in Python 3 makes this easy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really passing the path as: `'D:\temp\lixo'`? Try escaping the backslash, like so: `'D:\\temp\\lixo'`. For more information on string escaping you can consult the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).

Answer (score 0):

For windows you need to change the slash direction here too :

```
# Python Library 
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import os

def create_directory(server_path, branch):
    if not os.path.exists(rserver_path):
       os.makedirs(rserver_path)
    os.makedirs(server_path + "\\" + branch) #  escaped backslash
```

That should help.  Also, as @lukeg said, all your slashes need to be escaped.  i.e '\' instead of '\'